# magento 2 composer installation issue in xampp with php 7.3.2

Tags: php, composer-php, magento-2.3

I just tried to install `Magento 2` on my local server `Xampp`

I installed the composer and when tried to run `composer install` in command prompt , I got a error

> amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module 3.2.9 requires php 7.1.3- 7.2.0 your php version 7.3.2 doesn't satisfy that requirment.

How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the  `amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module` package requires PHP version `7.2`. You're on PHP version `7.3.2` which is not supported by version `3.2.9` of the package (yet).

You have multiple options to resolve the issue:

1. Downgrade to PHP 7.2.x to match the package's requirements.
2. Try to install a newer version of the package or directly from the master branch.

   If the compatibility with PHP 7.3 has been added to the package's composer.json i.e. in a newer version or on the master branch you can use:

   ```sh
   # install the master branch
   composer require 'amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module:dev-master'

   # install a version greater than 3.2.9
   composer require 'amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module:~3.2.10'
   ```
3. Ignore the PHP version requirement for a single `composer install` with:

   ```sh
   composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
   ```
4. Override the PHP version in your `composer.json`.

   ```
   "config": {
     "platform": {
        "php": "7.2.21"
     }
   }
   ```

   This way all subsequent runs of `composer install|update` will resolve the PHP to version `7.2.21`.

Comment: Sadly from what I see in amzn repo, 3.2.9 is still the latest version and it is still `~7.1.3||~7.2.0` so the option 2 seems off (source: https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/blob/master/src/Core/composer.json)

Comment: I opened [Issue#552](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/issues/552) on GitHub to inform Amazon about the lack of PHP 7.3 support in their Amazon Pay sub-packages.

Comment: Thank you Nicolai for this detailed solution .

I had to downgrade php .